# Search entries containing particular text using prepared statement

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table containing text

```
create table my_table(
    id integer primary key,
    para text
);
```

I want to select all entries that contain a particular field

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text LIKE '%searchtext%';
```

So it will give me all fields that contains "searchtext". Is there any aggregate function / procedure like `contain(...)` in postgresql to do the same.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE contains(text, 'searchtext');
```

I want the above behaviour because I am using prepared statement to provide parameter in where string e.g. `WHERE text = ?` then I am providing parameter in the place of `?`.

Comment: `where para like concat('%', ?, '%')` should work

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm sorry. I should have mentioned this. I am using prepared statement for security reason. If I will use your method, even then somebody can pass something like `abc%' OR '%def` (sql injection).

Comment: The `?` **is** the parameter for the PreparedStatement. It will not be vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use wildcards with a parameter in a PreparedStatement, you need to concatenate that parameter value with the wildcards:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE para LIKE concat('%', ?, '%');
```

The above is *not* vulnerable to SQL injection. Even if you did pass `abc%' OR '%def` as a parameter, the condition that gets used would be `LIKE '%abc%'' OR ''%def'`

Another possibility would be to use `strpos()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE strpos(para, ?) > 0;
```